# Add to string variable (string is a query)

Tags: php, sql, variables

i have a simple query who select me 3 news from table, but i wont to change this number from other file whith variable.

So this is query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 3';
```

I tried differently, but did not work...
Help please

My code(i can't answer on my question so i add it here)

```
$newsAmount = 3;
function get_news() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $newsAmount";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $news = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $news[] = $row;
    }
    return $news;
    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . " in " . $query);
    }
}
```

This is this code.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer if none has addressed the issue of [variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can just do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $newsAmount";
```

But make sure to keep the string in double quotes so the variable can be evaluated, Single quotes will be printed out as it is.

Try to echo $query, you will notice that its being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newsAmount = 3;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT ' + $newsAmount;
```

Comment: you should use `.` as an appending operator. This will not append instead add value of `$newsAmount` with equivalent value of the string.proof [here](http://3v4l.org/Lflef)

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: with dot (.) same warning

Comment: What does mysql_error() say the reason for the failure is?

Comment: @user2022879 post your code where you was executing the query

Comment: return $news;
    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . " in " . $query);
    }

Comment: The `if` isn't being executed because `return $news` exits the function. Put the `if` _before_ `return`.

Comment: ok, chack it, now it say - Notice: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT in F:\OpenServer\live-latvia\localhost\include\methods\function.php on line 17

Comment: i understad, now i have question , how can i use variable in function. my function doesn see this one/

Comment: Either it should be a parameter to the function, or use a `global` declaration in the function to access the global variable.

Comment: now in function i wrote - global $newsAmount;
and this variable work :) tnx for help

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return an array like you did in your code.
I would suggest to do the query inside your main code instead of writing it in a function.